# How to plot only lower half of scatterplot matrix using plotly figure_factory?

Tags: python, plot, plotly

i saw this example from ploty figure_factory

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 4),
                columns=['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C', 'Column D'])

df['Fruit'] = pd.Series(['apple', 'apple', 'grape', 'apple', 'apple',
                                'grape', 'pear', 'pear', 'apple', 'pear',
                                'apple', 'apple', 'grape', 'apple', 'apple',
                                'grape', 'pear', 'pear', 'apple', 'pear'])


fig = ff.create_scatterplotmatrix(df, diag='histogram',index='Fruit',
                                  height=800, width=800)
fig.show()
```

And there is the plot:
[image]

But i want to know if it possible to plot just the lowerhalft because the upperhalft is the same.
That is possible with lotly.graph_objects (thanks to **showupperhalf=False** : for example

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/iris-data.csv')
index_vals = df['class'].astype('category').cat.codes

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Splom(
                dimensions=[dict(label='sepal length',
                                 values=df['sepal length']),
                            dict(label='sepal width',
                                 values=df['sepal width']),
                            dict(label='petal length',
                                 values=df['petal length']),
                            dict(label='petal width',
                                 values=df['petal width'])],
                showupperhalf=False, # remove plots on diagonal
                text=df['class'],
                marker=dict(color=index_vals,
                            showscale=False, # colors encode categorical variables
                            line_color='white', line_width=0.5)
                ))


fig.update_layout(
    title='Iris Data set',
    width=600,
    height=600,
)

fig.show()
```

And there is the result:
[image]

It to possible to have the same with figure_factory?
Thanks in advance

Or it possible to change the scatterplot from go.Splom to a histogram?or box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer:

You can blank out any subplot you'd like by replacing all traces within that subplot with an empty trace object like `go.Scatter()`

---

#### The details:

[Scatterplot Matrix](https://plotly.com/python/splom/) does not seem to have an option for histograms on the diagonal. And [ff.create_scatterplotmatrix](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.figure_factory.create_scatterplotmatrix.html) does not seem to have an option for hiding parts of the matrix. That does not mean that what you're trying to do here is impossible though.

The complete code snippet below uses a matrix...

```
shows = array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
              [1., 1., 0., 0.],
              [1., 1., 1., 0.],
              [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

...to decide whether or not the data for each subplot of your scatterplot matrix should be shown. If `value = 0`, then a particular trace within a subplot...

```
Histogram({
    'marker': {'color': 'rgb(31, 119, 180)'},
    'showlegend': False,
    'x': [-1.4052399956918005, -1.8538677019305498, -0.0016298185761457061,
          -0.5268239747464603, -0.10652357762295094, 0.02921346151566477,
          -0.4581921321144815, 0.020997665069043978, 0.8734380864952216,
          -1.3008441288553083],
    'xaxis': 'x',
    'yaxis': 'y'
})
```

... is replaced by simply:

```
go.Scatter()
```

And if this happens for all traces in a subplot, then the plot is blanked out like you can see here:

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

cols = ['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C', 'Column D']
# cols = ['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C']
# cols = ['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C', 'Column D', 'Column E', 'Column F']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, len(cols)),
                columns=cols)

df['Fruit'] = pd.Series(['apple', 'apple', 'grape', 'apple', 'apple',
                                'grape', 'pear', 'pear', 'apple', 'pear',
                                'apple', 'apple', 'grape', 'apple', 'apple',
                                'grape', 'pear', 'pear', 'apple', 'pear'])

fig = ff.create_scatterplotmatrix(df, diag='histogram', index='Fruit',
                                  height=800, width=800)


# get number of rows and columns
ix = df['Fruit'].unique()
xs = []
ys = []
fig.for_each_xaxis(lambda x: xs.append(x.title.text) if x.title.text != None  else ())
fig.for_each_yaxis(lambda y: ys.append(y.title.text) if y.title.text != None  else ())

# build matrix to determine visiblity of trqces
m = (len(xs), len(ys))
show = np.tril(np.ones(m))
newshows = []
newdata = []
for i in range(0, len(show[0])):
    lst = list(np.repeat(show[i], len(ix)))
    newshows.extend(lst)

# replace existing data with empty data in the upper triangle
for t, s in enumerate(newshows):
    if  newshows[t] == 0:
        newdata.append(go.Scatter())
    else:
        newdata.append(fig.data[t])
        
fig.data = []
for i, new in enumerate(newdata):
    fig.add_trace(newdata[i])

fig.show()
```

Comment: Oh thank you :-) .... So i guess the flexibility will be how to generate automatically **show** depending on the number of Columns in my dataframe.

Comment: @herbigjson Yes. But as long as you've got the same number of traces in each subplot (and I don't see any reason why you shouldn't) then you should be fine. Id you'd like, I can take a closer look on how to make this dynamic wrt the number of columns in a dataframe.

Comment: @vesland now i will take a look on how to make that dynamically because in my i'm not geting the same number of trace (it just was an example)... it can be 4 or it can bit 8 or 12 traces. So I have to to it dynamically :)

Comment: @herbigjson I'm working on a more flexible approach. I'll share later tonight if you're interested.

Comment: @verstland I was able to do that:
`ml=[]
for j in range(1,len(test_list)+1):
    m = []
    loc = all_ - j
    print(loc)
    for t in range(1,j+1):
        m.append(True)
    for k in range(1,loc+1):
        m.append(False)
    ml.append(m)
`
output:
**[[True, False, False], [True, True, False], [True, True, True]]**

Comment: @herbigjson Cool! If my suggestion was helpful, please consider an upvote and/or marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: it looks a little bit weird but it just because a did it fast as test haha :-)

Comment: Of course... i forgot

Comment: can you tell me why you do **np.repeat(show[i], 3)**? Why 3?

Comment: @herbigjson That's because the first line `[T, F, F, F]` reflects the number of subplots in the first row. But in order to address the *traces* of the subplots, of which there are 3), we need the first line to be represented as `[T, T, T, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F]`. So the original values are repeated 3 times each. I'll provide a suggestion that does this a bit more elegantly.

Comment: thanks for your time and the new answer... it also works... but it is a probelm by **np.repeat(show[i],len(xs)-1)**.... it seems that the number **only** 3 has to come the. If it less than 3, we don't get the lowerhalf of the plot and if it is more than 3, we get an Error by newdata.append(fig.data[t]). And that also when the number of columns is  4, 5 or more.... that is the reaseon why i asked why does that work only with 3. you can check what i'm saying by adding one or two columns

Comment: @herbigjson Interesting! I'll test this a bit more on other datasets when I find the time.